# How to make a protocol inherits base model functions

Tags: python-3.x, generics, mypy, python-typing, typing

I'm writing a library to extend some abilities of Django Models.

Everything works just fine, the problem is the model needs to be decorated with a specific decorator that I created and for mypy it is a completely different class now.

So I've tried to use `Protocols` to inherit the decorated model's functions, like so...

```py
M = TypeVar('M', bound=models.Model, covariant=True)

class WatchedModel(Protocol[M]):
    @classmethod
    def watched_operation(
        cls, operation: str, target: TargetType, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Any:
        ...

T = TypeVar('T', bound='models.Model')

def watched(watcher, watched_managers) -> Callable[[Type[T]], Type['WatchedModel[T]']]:
    def decorator(cls: Type[T]) -> Type['WatchedModel[T]']:
       ...
       # implementation doesn't matter

    return decorator

@watched(...)
class CreateModel(models.Model):
    def test_func(self):
        pass
```

Here you can see that an instance of CreateModel is in fact a WatchedModel of CreateModel on mypy.

[image: This image shows on vscode that an instance of the decorated model is a generic protocol of that model]

But I can't have predictions to Django `models.Model` functions nor the `test_func` that I declared.

[image: This images shows on vscode that mypy can't infer Django nor explicitly declared model functions]

Comment: What you need in fact is an Intersection type. I think it is one of the most wanted features, but [not implemented yet](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) - and doesn't seem to be here soon. There is some context in that issue. How many watched models do you have?